Power of a point; non-concentric circumferences

Let $C_1,C_2$ be two circles with distinct centres $O_1,O_2$ and $H$ the point of intersection of $O_{1}O_{2}$ with the radical axis. Then, given any point $P$ on the plane:
$$Pot(P,C_2)-Pot(P,C_1)=2\overrightarrow{O_2O_1} \cdot \overrightarrow{HP}$$ where $Pot(P,C_1)$ stands for the power of $P$ wrt to the circle $C_1$.

I tried writing $\overrightarrow{HP}=\overrightarrow{HO_1}+\overrightarrow{O_1P}$; but couldn't find a way to reach the other member; any suggestions?
EDIT: $$H=(0,0); O_1=(a,0); O_2=(a',0); P=(x,y)$$
\begin{align*}
& Pot(P,C_2)-Pot(P,C_1)=(x-a')^2+y^2-{r_2}^2-((x-a)^2+y^2-r_1^2) \\[7pt]
= & \; x^2-2a'x+{a'}^2-{r_2}^2-x^2+2ax-a^2+r_1^2 \\
=&2(a-a')x+{a'}^2-{r_2}^2+r_1^2-a^2\\[7pt]
=& \;2\langle (a-a',0);(x,y) \rangle +\underbrace{Pot(H,C_2)-Pot(H,C_1)}_{0}\\[7 pt]
= & \;2\overrightarrow{O_2O_1} \cdot \overrightarrow{HP}
\end{align*}

A circumference is a distance. You should use the word circle, which refers to the geometric figure of points equidistant from a centre. (A circle together with its interior is called a disk)

1/ That's not the formula for the power of a point. $\quad$ 2/ Note that $H = (0,0)$ being on the radical axis only holds for specific values of $r_1, r_2$, which you're not accounting for. It's not immediately apparent if that will impact the calculations. $\quad$ 3/ It's not clear to me what you mean by "reach the other member". Can you elaborate?
